# Como faço para meu App receber notificação mesmo fechado ou bloqueado

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, push-notification

Se eu bloqueio a tela do mey Cell e deixo o App aberto, eu recebo Notificações, porém se fecho o App não consigo mais receber. O problema que quando começou a funcionar, estava recebendo em todas as situações e de repente não funcionou mais. Estou tentando entender o que foi feito, pois do nada não tem como parar de 
funcionar.
Envio:

```
public static async Task<IFCMResponse> SenderMessage()
        {
            FCMClient client = new FCMClient("XXXXXXXXXXX"); //as derived from https://console.firebase.google.com/project/
            var message = new Message()
            {
                To = "XXXXXXXXXX", //topic example /topics/all
                Notification = new AndroidNotification()
                {
                    Body = "Solicitação de Novo Desconto",
                    Title = "Desconto",
                }
            };
            var result = await client.SendMessageAsync(message);
            return result;
        }
```

Classe que processa as notificações:

```
[assembly: Permission(Name = "com.global.autorizador.br.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "com.global.autorizador.br.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.INTERNET")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK")]
//GET_ACCOUNTS is only needed for android versions 4.0.3 and below
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS")]

namespace Gcm.Client
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Permission = Gcm.Client.Constants.PERMISSION_GCM_INTENTS)]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { Gcm.Client.Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_MESSAGE }, Categories = new string[] { "com.global.autorizador.br" })]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { Gcm.Client.Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_REGISTRATION_CALLBACK }, Categories = new string[] { "com.global.autorizador.br" })]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { Gcm.Client.Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_LIBRARY_RETRY }, Categories = new string[] { "com.global.autorizador.br" })]
    public class PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver : GcmBroadcastReceiverBase<GcmService>
    {
        public static string[] SENDER_IDS = new string[] {Constants.SENDER_ID };
    }
    [Service]
    public class GcmService : GcmServiceBase
    {
        public static string RegistrationID { get; private set; }

        public GcmService()
            : base(PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver.SENDER_IDS) { }

        protected override void OnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
        {
            Log.Verbose("PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver", "GCM Registered: " + registrationId);
            RegistrationID = registrationId;
        }

        protected override void OnMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.Info("PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver", "GCM Message Received!");

            var msg = new StringBuilder();

            if (intent != null && intent.Extras != null)
            {
                foreach (var key in intent.Extras.KeySet())
                    msg.AppendLine(key + "=" + intent.Extras.Get(key).ToString());
            }

            //Store the message
            var prefs = GetSharedPreferences(context.PackageName, FileCreationMode.Private);
            var edit = prefs.Edit();
            edit.PutString("last_msg", msg.ToString());
            edit.Commit();

            string message = intent.Extras.GetString("message");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                createNotification("New todo item!", "Todo item: " + message);
                return;
            }

            string msg2 = intent.Extras.GetString("msg");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg2))
            {
                createNotification("New hub message!", msg2);
                return;
            }

            createNotification("Solicitação de novo desconto", msg.ToString());
        }

        void createNotification(string title, string desc)
        {
            //Create notification
            var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

            //Create an intent to show ui
            var uiIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));

            //Use Notification Builder
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

            //Create the notification
            //we use the pending intent, passing our ui intent over which will get called
            //when the notification is tapped.
            var notification = builder.SetContentIntent(PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, uiIntent, 0))
                                      .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                                      .SetTicker(title)
                                      .SetContentTitle(title)
                                      .SetContentText(desc)

                    //Set the notification sound
                    .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification))

                    //Auto cancel will remove the notification once the user touches it
                    .SetAutoCancel(true).Build();

            //Show the notification
            notificationManager.Notify(1, notification);
        }

        protected override void OnUnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
        {
            Log.Error("PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver", "Unregistered RegisterationId : " + registrationId);
        }

        protected override void OnError(Context context, string errorId)
        {
            Log.Error("PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver", "GCM Error: " + errorId);
        }

    }
```

Comment: tente implementar um [foreground service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/foreground-services/) para receber as suas notificações.

Comment: @TobiasMesquita, li o link passado e não sei se é isso que eu estou querendo. O que eu quero, é por exemplo estou anadndo na rua ou almoçando e de repente recebo a notificação que existe um novo desconto para ser concedido. Normalmente nestes casos, no cel está tudo fechado. É disso que eu estou falando.